# ambito del this en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

me econtre con un problema mientras trato de programar algo en javascript.
Pasa que estoy usando una clase javascript y en un metodo de la clase tengo que recorrer un objecto jquery con each.
Lo que pasa es que una vez adentro del each no puedo accesar a las propiedades y metodos de la clase.. porque el ambito del this en el each hace referencia al elemento actual que esta recorriendo y no a alguna propiedad de la clase.
mi pregunta es si hay otra forma de hacer referencia a propiedades y metodos de la clase estando en el each.
pongo un codigo de ejemplo.
Intente recorrer el objecto con un bucle comun pero me arroja todas las propiedades y metodos que tiene el objeto jquery

```
class example{
 constructor(){
  this.prop;
  this.ob=$("#objquery")
 }
  metodo(){
   this.ob.each(function(i)){
    this.otrometodo() //no puedo accesarlo porque dice que no esta definido por el cambio de ambito del objeto this
    this.prop //tampoco puedo accesarlo
    }
 }
 otrometodo(){alert()}
 }
```

bueno eso basicamente es que me cambia el ambito del objecto this y presiso usar metodos y propiedades de la clase en el each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que la hay, tendrías que redefinir el this con una nueva variable llama _self($self, $this) como gustes llamarla. Y redefinirla dentro de la función método() pero no dentro del each, así:

```
class example {
    constructor() {
        this.prop;
        this.ob = $("#objquery")
    }
    metodo() {
        const _self = this;
        this.ob.each(function (i)) {
            _self.otrometodo() //no puedo accesarlo porque dice que no esta definido por el cambio de ambito del objeto this
            _self.prop //tampoco puedo accesarlo
        }
    }
    otrometodo() {
        alert()
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo !! esto resuelve mi problema